# Как обновить данные, имея массив объектов?

Tags: postgresql

Допустим есть массив данных

```
id название  количество
1  банан             2
2  арбуз             6
3  яблоко            8
```

И есть таблица.

```
id название  тип количество 
1  банан  фрукт     1
2 арбуз   фрукт     2
3 яблоко фрукт      76
4 капуста овощ      111
```

Как в 1 запросе обновить таблицу? А не делать запрос update для каждого id фрукта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только костылём типа

```
INSERT INTO some_table(id, name, count)
VALUES
  (1, 'банан', 2),
  (2, 'арбуз', 6),
  (3, 'яблоко', 8),
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
  SET name = EXCLUDED.name,
      count = EXCLUDED.count;
```

*Кстати, арбуз - это ягода.*